# Verify authenticity of an client

Tags: c#, security, hash, client-server, verification

I have the following concern about security in server-client models...

Imagine the following:

I have an C# WinForms client that wants to communicate with a server (PHP GET-POST Requests, Socket or WebSocket in a Console App C# (Net Framework) running on a Debian under Mono, instead of using ASP.NET).

The first problem that arises is that whether the server (written in PHP or C #) must have some kind of control for the anonymous requests that the client generates, for this, we will have to use some type of token generated by the server to every request.

The problem isn't related to the token (my plan is to use HTTPS (PHP) or SSL / TLS + Certificates in WebSockets (C#) for client-server communications at the network level, to avoid Spoofing or MitM).

The problem arises when the server has to give to a "client" (we need to check its validity, that the main concern) a token to allow the client do requests. It would be very easy to any client to give a token from the server (How? Replicating (inverse ingeenering) a client that makes requests to the server to try to obtain valid tokens, at least, as I plan to implement it, hence the need for help).

In what I was thinking, is to generate a md5 or sha hash for the assembly file of the client. So, if anyone tries to replicate those steps, it will be difficult. Because he/she will need to modify the source code of the assembly or make a malicious assembly and obtain the same hash by collision (this is difficult).

I do not know how efficient is this system, so I need you to guide me a bit in this aspect.

I've been looking at OAuth, and I think that this type of implementation is not the one I'm looking for, because this kind of implementations is for the user level (to avoid that another user violates the main user data), not for the client (application).

So if someone can guide on this issue it would be of great help.

Answer (score 2):

You can't authenticate the client, it is not possible. Anything in the client is known to the user (attacker), any secret, anything you have there. The only question is difficulty, but anything you do, it will not be very difficult.

Also in your hashing scheme, what would you do with the hash, send it to the server? Why would a different client have to match the hash, when it can send whatever it wants (ie. the correct hash, as sniffed from the network)?

So again, because the software needs to run on the client machine, anything that runs there or is sent on the network is disclosed to the user, and he can replicate it in a different client. It is not possible to securely prevent this. Also ssl/tls doesn't help here, if you control one of the endpoints (ie.the client).

Imagine if it was possible somehow, software piracy would not be a thing - but it very much is.